# How to prevent class attribute from being modified from outside class

Tags: python, oop, getter-setter, private-members

In the example below, my objective is to prevent modification of the `position` attribute from outside the class `Asset`. I was able to achieve that by creating a setter method. As a result, calling `cash.position = 1000` from outside results in an error.

The problem is: if I call `cash._position = 1000` from outside the class I am still able to modify it.

```
class Asset:

    def __init__(self, start=0):
        self._position = start

    # Getter
    @property
    def position(self):
        print("property class method called")
        print("position = {}".format(self._position))
        return self._position

    # Setter
    @position.setter
    def __position(self, value): # Private method - can't be accessed from outside class
        print("@position.setter method called")
        self._position = value

    def transact(self, value):
        print("transact method called")
        self._position = self.position + value

cash = Asset(start=50)
cash.position

cash = Asset()
print(cash.position)
cash.transact(30)
print(cash.position)
cash.transact(-60)
print(cash.position)
cash.position = 1000 # OK - does not allow to change position
cash._position = 1000 # Problem - does allow to change position
cash.position
```

Comment: Python doesn't have private variables.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, python doesn't really have a concept of [access modifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables). What prepending a variable name with `__` really does is instruct python to [mangle](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) the name ie. to replace it with `_classname__varname`. This is mostly useful when subclassing.
Prepending a variable name with `_` (a single underscore) is a conventional way to identify a variable that is supposed to be considered private by a user. In theory, this is enough of a access modifier, as the user is properly warned that messing with such values will break encapsulation.

There is however a fairly good way to implement the behavior you probably want, and it is by using the `property` decorator (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property). Consider this code:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, temperature):
        self.temperature = temperature

    @property
    def temperature(self):
        print("GET")
        return self.__temperature

    @temperature.setter
    def temperature(self, value):
        print("SET")
        self.__temperature = value

c = C(10)
print(c.temperature)
```

Output:

```
SET
GET
10
```

Answer (score 1):

Leave the setter undefined if you don't want to provide public access to the underlying attribute. You can use `__position` instead of `_position` if you like, but even that isn't guaranteed to prevent someone from changing it value: you could do so with `cash.__Asset_position = ...`.

```
class Asset:

    def __init__(self, start=0):
        self._position = start

    @property
    def position(self):
        return self._position

    def transact(self, value):
        self._position = self.position + value
        # or
        # self._position += value
```